# Invertible matrix and polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Show that given $A^2+2A+I=0$, $A$ is invertible and find $A^{-1}$.

How do I resolve this, please?

Comment: Note that
$$I=A(-A-2I)=(-A-2I)A$$

Comment: The inverse would be equal a $-A-2I$? Or $A^{-}=-A-2I$

Comment: Yes, an inverse $B$ of a square matrix $A$ by definition is a square matrix which satisfies $$AB=BA=I$$

Comment: With this point of view if we have $A^5+2A^4-5A^2-A+7I=0$, the inverse matrix is: $A\left(A^4+2A^3-5A-I\right)=-7I\Leftrightarrow A\left(\dfrac{A^4+2A^3-5A-I}{-7}\right)=I\Rightarrow A^{-1}=\left(\dfrac{A^4+2A^3-5A-I}{-7}\right)$